# How i can cut java stacktrace for selenium test?

Tags: java, python, selenium, automated-tests

Same actions for java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Lol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://suninjuly.github.io/simple_form_find_task.html");
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
    }
}
```

and python

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://suninjuly.github.io/simple_form_find_task.html")
button = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
```

but stacktraces are very different it terms of information value:

- java 35 lines
- python 14 lines

i didnt paste stacktraces due to security reasons, but you can check blurred screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsTLv.jpg

*java stacktrace even does not fit in macbook 13' screen :c*

How i can restrict printing unwanted information except actual trace?

Comment: Why would you NOT want all the error information? It's telling you there's a problem. If you don't want to see the errors, fix the problems until you get down to just the stack trace.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: There is no any code screenshots, only screenshots of stacktraces and plain text

Comment: @JeffC: Even though imgur at the moment appears to be having problems with the SSL cert (image is unviewable) I think the screenshot is meant to illustrate the problem he was talking about from a visual standpoint. I don't think keran means for the code to be read, but to give us a visual that helps put this question in context.

Comment: @keran Screenshots are for UI. If it's text like code, HTML, error messages, stack traces, etc. it should all be put into the question and formatted as text. When that screenshot is gone from imgur, this question will have no context.

Comment: @GregBurghardt See my comment above... and your point of SSL cert issues is yet another reason to not post text as screenshots. There's no reason he can't post all of that text as actual text. We can then use copy/paste it to google the error message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Firefox and Geckodriver is that it produces so many log entries which are not relevant for most users. To reduce the log entries in your Java program you have following options:

1. Use a different Browser e.g. Chrome which produces less log entries.
2. Redirect the Geckodriver log entries.

You can redirect the log entries of Geckodriver with following line to a file:

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"C:\\temp\\logs.txt");
```

For more information see [this link](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/disable-firefox-logs-selenium/).

Comment: this link is about devtools console logs, not webdriver logs in IDE

Comment: What do you mean with devtools logs? Have you tried it? This link provides a solution on how to redirect the geckodriver log entries (Most of your log entries come from geckodriver).

Comment: yes, i tried the solution

amount of  "non-stacktrace" information in my IDE after exception remains the same